# Laravel - Customize :attribute value?

Tags: laravel

I have a page with 2 forms. Since the `id` attribute of HTML elements must be unique, I prefixed my ids with `login_` and `register_`. I'm using `Request` objects to handle those requests : I made a `LoginRequest` and a `RegisterRequest`, and set the rules in the `rules()` method.

However, when printing the errors, I know have a message like :

> The login email field is required.

Is there any way I can tell Laravel that even if the `id` of my `input` is `login_email`, I would like him to print *email* (i.e. without the prefix) ? I know I can return custom messages by implementing the `messages()` method, however I would like to avoid doing that, since the default messages are good for me, just the value of the `:attribute` object that makes the error message a bit hard to understand.

Comment: I don;t think you can do this without, custom messages. Jut wondering why can't name two input fields with same name ? Backend can work with name instead of ids i think

Comment: Oh you're right. Didn't know that, awesome !

Comment: you may implement the attributes method in your request

    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'login_email' => 'email'
        ];
    }